# Count numer of elements in a set of objects

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I have a question about getting the count of objects after following 2 foreign key relationships, as an annotation of a QuerySet.

Let's say I have the following models:

```
class TaskList(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64)

class Batch(models.Model):
    task_list = models.ForeignKey(TaskList)
    length = models.IntegerField()
    done = models.BooleanField(default=False)

class Task(models.Model):
    batch = models.ForeignKey(Batch)
    task_name = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    # some more fields..
```

Batch has a set of Tasks. An object Task is created when the corresponding task is done.

I can get the number of Questions of every poll by doing this:

```
TaskList.objects.all().annotate(total_tasks=Sum('batch_set__length'))
```

How can I get the number of Tasks a TaskList has? I tried doing

```
TaskList.objects.all().annotate(total_tasks=Count('batch_set__task_set'))
```

but it did not work.

There doesn't seem to be anything in [the documentation on annotations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/aggregation/) about following a foreign key relationship more than once, or about a way to annotate the batches.

Comment: I'm looking through some of my previous Django code to reference how I did it, but can't you just import the other model you are trying to count, do an objects.all() and do a object.task.count?

I know this is an extra query so not your ideal solution, but just a thought if nothing better comes up.

Comment: Yes, I'll do that until I find a more elegant solution. Apparently the correct way of doing this is with subqueries, but it is slower than what I had before. Thanks!